# If $G$ is a group and a,b $\in$ G such that $a^2 = b^2$ then $a=b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

True or false? Prove or give a counter-example

If $G$ is a group and a,b $\in$ G such that $a^2 = b^2$ then $a=b$

My attempt:

$a^2 = b^2$

$aa = bb$

$aaa^{-1}=bba^{-1}$

$a(aa^{-1})=bba^{-1}$

$a = bba^{-1}$

$a = b^2a^{-1}$

I am kind of stuck

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is false even in the non-zero reals under multiplication. For instance, $(-1)^2 = 1^2$

Answer (score 4):

The statement is true in *finite* groups if and only if $|G|$ is *odd*. For if $|G|$ is odd, the by Bézout's Theorem we can find integers $m$ and $n$ such that $1=m|G|+2n$. Hence, if $a^2=b^2$, then $a=a^1=a^{m|G|+2n}=$ (apply Lagrange $a^{|G|}=1$) $a^{2n}=(a^2)^n=(b^2)^n=$ (reasoning back with $b$)=$b$. The other way, if for every pair $a,b \in G$ $a^2=b^2$ implies $a=b$ and $|G|$ is even, then by Cauchy's Theorem we can find and element $a$ of order $2$, that is $a^2=1$ and $a \neq 1$, which contradicts the premise.

Answer (score 3):

Check in the Klein group $\;\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2\;$ ...